# How to create a tabpage on button click of a form containing usercontrol tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have created a tabcontrol user control. and i have imported it on a form (callled a test.cs) which already contains a button.
I wish to add a property to the user control(tabcontrol, here called customtabcontrol) that whenever i click the button on window form (called test.cs) on which that usercontrol lies then it
must add a tabpage to that usercontrol tabcontrol.

My code for usercontrol is :

```
namespace TestWizard
{
    public partial class customtabcontrol : UserControl
    {
        public customtabcontrol()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the view of usercontrol http://prntscr.com/ap9qi7

My test form is :

```
namespace TestWizard
{
    public partial class test : Form
    {
        public test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customtabcontrol tb = new customtabcontrol();
            TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Tab");
            tp.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "testing by shekhar" });
            tb.TabPages.Add(tp); //this line will obviously give the error as tb cannot add tabpage , but how to add on it ?

        }
    }
}
```

And its view is : http://prntscr.com/ap9rj2

How to add tabpage on my usercontrol by test.cs form button click ? **Please note that this button is on the Form not on the usercontrol**

Comment: It is not clear at all why you made UserControl the base class.  It is much simpler when you derive from TabControl instead. If it must be a UC then you'll have to add a property that exposes the TabControl.  Or a method that adds a TabPage.

Comment: May bye u did not understood what i wish to accomplish. I have a user control which contains a tabcontrol, right ? and then build program and i add another form containing a button on it. Then i import that usercontrol (which actually is a tabcontrol) and put on the the test.cs form. Now when i clcik this button it must add a tabpage in the customized tabcontrol. and must be able to add as many pages as possible by button click in this UC-tabcontrol dyanmically.  Now did u got it ? How to achieve this ?

Comment: My situation is that upon click on a button (which do not exist in that user control) i have to generate event in UC-tabcontrol. Like addind tabpages to it ..and then in future i may be adding UI(labels, textboxes , combo etc.) on those tabpages which i got on button click.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a TabPages collection property to your UserControl:

```
public customtabcontrol() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

public TabControl.TabPageCollection TabPages {
  get { return tabControl1.TabPages; }
}
```

Comment: yaah it solved teh error in line tb.TabPages.Add(tp);  but still it do not add any tabpage.

Comment: It does.  Your posted code in the button click is creating a new UserControl that is never getting added to the form.  Use the control that you created in the designer.

Comment: So how to solve it ? sorry i am not able to underrstand

Comment: Ok, but i wish to update the usercontrol on button click (i mean i must have tabpage obtained on the same usercontrol tabpage)

Comment: @testtest What's the name of the control on the form?  customtabcontrol1?  If so, then it's just `customtabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Hello"));`